# How to change values to time class as hours e.g. "1" to "01:00"

Tags: r, datetime, tidyr, lubridate

My dataset has times listed as 0-23 hours in the day. They have been imported in RStudio as character class, reading as 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, etc to 23. I need these to both become a time class and to read in proper hour:minutes time format (00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00). Doesn't particularly matter the time class but it needs to only include hours:minutes. This column is called hours.

```
A tibble: 6 × 10
##   date       station hours AMB_TEMP    CO    NO   NO2   NOx    O3  PM10
##   <date>     <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 2015-01-01 Cailiao 00          16  0.74   1      15    16    35   171
## 2 2015-01-01 Cailiao 01          16  0.7    0.8    13    14    36   174
## 3 2015-01-01 Cailiao 02          15  0.66   1.1    13    14    35   160
## 4 2015-01-01 Cailiao 03          15  0.61   1.7    12    13    34   142
## 5 2015-01-01 Cailiao 04          15  0.51   2      11    13    34   123
## 6 2015-01-01 Cailiao 05          14  0.51   1.7    13    15    32   110
```

I tried changing the class of `hours` to POSIXct and specifying the format. It doesn't give me an error but also doesn't do anything. I also tried using subtr and strptime with the same results.

```
cleantimedata <- timedata %>% 
mutate(as.POSIXct(hours, format="%H%M"))

mutate(substr(hours, 0, nchar(hours)-2)) %>% 
mutate(paste0(hours, ':', mins))

strftime(strptime(sapply(paste0(hours), function(i) substring(i, nchar(i) - 3,   nchar(i))),    "%H%M"), format = "%H:%M")
```

I tried changing to numeric or parsing the numbers in the column first. This removes the second digit (00 to 0) but doesn't change the outcome of the above. The format is definitely too simple to work with parse_time but I tried anyway

```
mutate(hours = parse_number(hours))
mutate(hours = parse_time(hours))
mutate(hours, as.numeric(hours))
```

UPDATE: I've found a (non-elegant) solution below. I still welcome other solutions with less code

```
clean_timedata <- timedata %>%
mutate(hours = stri_pad_right(hours, 4, 0)) %>% 
mutate(hours = gsub('(..)(?=.)', '\\1:', hours, perl=TRUE)) %>% 
mutate(hours = parse_time(hours)) %>% 
mutate(substr(hours, 1, 5)) %>% 
select(-hours) %>% 
rename("time" = "substr(hours, 1, 5)") %>%
```

Comment: I have found a code solution to my problem above, albeit not the most elegant. I still welcome simpler/more elegant solutions (mine involves about 7 steps currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would paste() work for you?

eg:

```
timedata <- tibble(hours = c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"))
timedata$hours <- paste(timedata$hours, ":00", sep = "")
timedata$hours
```